# How to add a currency filter in odoo enterprise 15 aged receivable report

Tags: enterprise, odoo-15, accounting

i have added this filter in enterprise report and it looks like this.i need to update the view based on the currency selected and make necessary currency conversions.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF5rl.png)

i am expecting a solution on how to do this